# How to stop and start a Asynctask.(Android)

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have button Start and Stop, and textview 
I want click button Start textview countdown 100->0. 
When I click button Stop countdown stop, then I click button Start again countdown continue.
Sorry my English not good.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
private Handler h = null;
final int delay = 2500; //millisecond
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //Stuff here
         }
        }
    };

//To stop Handler when you leave your activity
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (h != null && myRunnable != null) h.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    Log.d(TAG, "Stop Handler");
}

//Call this when you want to start your work
public void StartHandler(){
    h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(myRunnable, delay);
    Log.d(TAG, "Start Handler");
}
```